# How can I get working selenium

Tags: java, selenium

The code below measure loading web page using java.
To read selenium i had imported :
selenium-standalone-server 2.28.0.jar & selenium-java 2.28.0.jar
but it seems that isn't suitable jars.
Any Idea how can I get working this code.

Code source of measure loading web page using java an selenium
[image]

The jars that I have imported

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the jars in your path?

Comment: @KorayTugay is right : add them in your classpath in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixe it by including the jars in selenium-2.53.0 folder 
I have downloaded from:http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 0):

i dont have exact amswer to ur query.but i suggest u follow these things:
1.use selenium-server-standalone.2.53.0.jar 
2.before launch the chrome browser,u should write following
       System.setPropoerty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chrome browser downlaod path");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();